# Python loop to combine two lists

Tags: python

Having trouble with concatenating two lists into another list.  Where each list item from one list is combined with every list item of the other list.

Example:

```
list_1 = ['a','b','c']
list_2 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

I am able to get the desired output in a print statement, using a for loop:

```
for x in list_1:
    for y in list_2:
        print(x,y)

output:
a one
a two
a three
b one
b two
b three
c one
c two
c three
```

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to assign this output to a new list

Comment: kindly post the expected output. Is it a list of tuples, a Pandas series/dataframe? is Pandas even required for this?

Comment: edited out the pandas tag since this is a pure python question and has nothing to do with pandas

Comment: Yes, the question itself is vague on what the expected output is. Without that, there can be numerous possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use the itertools library and make it a one-liner.

```
import itertools

list_1 = ['a','b','c']
list_2 = ['one', 'two', 'three'] 

list_3 = itertools.product(list_1, list_2)

print(list(list_3))
```

Answer (score 3):

A list comprehension can also be used.

```
list_1 = ['a','b','c']
list_2 = ['one', 'two', 'three'] 

print([(a, b) for a in list_1 for b in list_2])
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'one'), ('a', 'two'), ('a', 'three'), ('b', 'one'), ('b', 'two'), ('b', 'three'), ('c', 'one'), ('c', 'two'), ('c', 'three')]
```

Comment: This is the best answer, using list comprehension is the best way to solve this problem, and also the faster.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a blank list, and append the values to it after each iteration:

```
list_1 = ['a','b','c']
list_2 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
list_3 = []
for x in list_1:
    for y in list_2:
        # In 1 line: list_3.extend([x, y]) 
        list_3.append(x)
        list_3.append(y)

print(list_3)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'one', 'a', 'two', 'a', 'three', 'b', 'one', 'b', 'two', 'b', 'three', 'c', 'one', 'c', 'two', 'c', 'three']
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
list_1 = ['a','b','c']
list_2 = ['one', 'two', 'three']

list_3 = []
for x in list_1:
    for y in list_2:
        list_3 += [x,y]

print(list_3)
```

Comment: This works, even if it takes more line than necessary to be written. +1

Comment: I knew it could be done using list comprehension, but I wanted to keep it simple for the OP and use his own code. The OP is clearly newer to python (no offence mate we all start somewhere). Baby steps for now ;)

Comment: Right thought WALL-E

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> [(i, inner_i )for i in ['a','b','c'] for inner_i in  ['one', 'two', 'three']]

[('a', 'one'),
 ('a', 'two'),
 ('a', 'three'),
 ('b', 'one'),
 ('b', 'two'),
 ('b', 'three'),
 ('c', 'one'),
 ('c', 'two'),
 ('c', 'three')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new list (list_3) and append values to it as tuples.

```
list_1 = ['a','b','c']
list_2 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
list_3 = []

for i, in list_1: 
    for j in list_2:
        print(i,j)
        k = i,j
        list_3.append(k)
```

Comment: I changed the code, check now.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_1 = ['a','b','c']
list_2 = ['one', 'two', 'three'] 
list_3 = [[a, b] for a in list_1 for b in list_2]

print(list_3)
```

output :

```
[['a', 'one'], ['a', 'two'], ['a', 'three'], ['b', 'one'], ['b', 'two'], ['b', 'three'], ['c', 'one'], ['c', 'two'], ['c', 'three']]
```

Answer (score 0):

A few of the answers worked to combine the lists but the following usage of itertools provided an output that was easiest to transfer into a dataframe column

```
from itertools import product
list_1 = ['a','b','c']
list_2 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
list_3 = ['you', 'and', 'me']

result = [f'{a} {b} {c}' for a, b, c in product(list_1, list_2, list_3)]

Output:

['a one you',
 'a one and',
 'a one me',
 'a two you',
 'a two and',
 'a two me',
 'a three you',
 'a three and',
 'a three me',
 'b one you',
 'b one and',
 'b one me',
 'b two you',
 'b two and',
 'b two me',
 'b three you',
 'b three and',
 'b three me',
 'c one you',
 'c one and',
 'c one me',
 'c two you',
 'c two and',
 'c two me',
 'c three you',
 'c three and',
 'c three me']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_1 = ['a','b','c']
list_2 = ['one', 'two', 'three']

#Initializing an empty list, then inserting it into the empty list
list_3 = []

#Loop
for x in list_1:
    for y in list_2:
        list_3 += [x,y]

#Print list_3
print(list_3)
```